# How do I display specific error messages

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-5.0

[Full Code - Pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/R3wUzB6y)

I am attempting to refine my PowerShell script by adding in error messages if they appear.

I am planning for

- If a Username already exists in our AD environment
- If the "NewUsername" text box is left blank

these are just the first 2 examples I can see causing a problem going forward.

I have been researching around, and I believe i should be using `try/catch` blocks.  However I am unsure of how to incorporate them, and how to pull specific error messages.

Do I do start that by adding the `try/catch` blocks at this location in the code?

```
$CreateAccount = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Button
$CreateAccount.Text = "Create Account"
$CreateAccount.Width = 127
$CreateAccount.Height = 27
$CreateAccount.Add_MouseClick({
#add here code triggered by the event
try
{
    #code to actually run here
}
catch
{
    #code to display error messages if any come up
}
```

If so, can someone point me in the right direction to grab the 2 error types so I can display them to the user running the script?

I feel I must also point out that I convert the .ps1 script to an .exe file with no console showing when it is ran.  Will this cause issues for that?

Comment: If you're asking how to display a message box with the error you could put something like this in the `catch` block: `[Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($_)`. This could be refined further, of course, depending on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Hey!
I used this article for error handling in my script.
http://pleasework.robbievance.net/howto-find-specific-exceptions-to-use-with-trycatch-in-powershell/

You can catch specific exceptions and spit any error message you want.

this is just an example of how to catch "access denied" exception


Catch [System.UnauthorizedAccessException]
    { echo "You don't have permissions"}

Not sure if it's what you are looking for

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers how would I find out what exact error messages to show?  Only ones I am worried about right now are if an account already exists with the supplied username, or if the user left the username text box blank?  The second one I am sure I can figure out since it wouldn't be a system generated error message.

Comment: There's no need to `try..catch` that. Just check if the value of the text field is empty, then check if the account already exists, and show an appropriate error message if one of these checks fails.

Comment: As suggested by Ansgar, you can check if the variable is Null and if yes, then go ahead and check the account is present or not. two if condition(nested) will do that

Comment: If you use `try{} catch [Exception] {}` you can nest if/elseif/else statements in the catch block and throw messages according to the exception type like @TeslaGreat explained.

In the ISE, you can see the properties of the current error with the following:

`$Error[0] | Get-Member`. One of the useful properties for your situation might be `$Error[0].CategoryInfo.Category` or `$Error[0].CategoryInfo.Reason`